# How to make Bootstrap Timepicker 100% clear for "dumbest user" - UX

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, user-experience

We want to use it in an online platform which allows users to book services. Time is a crucial information. It is possible that unexperienced users want to book a service.

How can you make sure that Bootstrap's Timepicker is 100% clear for any kind of user?

[image]

As the page will be international, I can imagine other language speaking users for example not to understand what HH means.

Comment: Pre-setting a default value instead of placeholders should make it clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I've heard people not even using placeholders because they are afraid, user's may think that the field is filled already, so they don't have to enter anything in there. I can't imagine how strong that argument is though.